# Change the opacity of a Particle object in Three.js (NOT ParticleSystem)?

Tags: three.js

I am using the `CanvasRenderer`and `Particle`in Three.JS.  I am generating some random particles using this approach:

```
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img.png");

material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({

    map : texture,
    transparent : true,

});

for (var i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {

    var particle = new THREE.Particle(material);

    particle.position.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    particle.position.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    particle.position.z = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

    // Set the size of the particle
    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = particle.scale.z =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2;

    particles.push(particle);
    scatterPlot.add(particle);

}
```

I would like to (if possible) be able to change the opacity of individual `Particles`, as I am using transparency as a dimension in my plot (i.e., transparency of a particle reflects the magnitude of a variable).  I know I can use `particle.material.opacity`, but that changes the opacity for all particles.  I tried `particles[i].material.opacity`but got the same result.

One possibility of course would be to have an array of materials with different opacities.  But I'm not sure if there's perhaps a simpler way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: This code looks old. What three.js version are you using? Search the three.js examples for `Sprite`, `SpriteCanvasMaterial`, `SpriteMaterial`.

Comment: `Particle` is deprecated. It is now `Sprite`. `ParticleBasicMaterial` is deprecated. Use `SpriteMaterial` with `CanvasRenderer`.

Comment: The reason I went with `Particle` is because it didn't look like `ParticleSystem` or `Sprite` would work with `RayCaster`.  This was kind of a deal breaker because I need to be able to detect intersections.  I will take a look to see if `Sprite` now supports raycasting. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Made the change to `THREE.Sprite` and `SpriteMaterial` and things seem to be working.  Although the `Canvas` demos on the ThreeJS page still have examples using `Particle`.  Thanks for pointing this info out, WestLangley.  As always, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might have figured this out -- and was simpler than I was thinking.  It at least seems to be working for me.  I moved the `material` declaration into the `for` loop.  I think this generates a different `ParticleBasicMaterial` for each `Particle`, but I suppose that is okay.

I am then able to access the individual `Particle's`material by using `particles[i].material`, which allows me to change the opacity of specific particles.

Here is my updated code:

```
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img.png");

for (var i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {

    material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({

        map : texture,
        transparent : true,

    });

    var particle = new THREE.Particle(material);

    particle.position.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    particle.position.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    particle.position.z = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

    // Set the size of the particle
    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = particle.scale.z =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2;

    particles.push(particle);
    scatterPlot.add(particle);

}

// Example opacity change
particles[0].material.opacity = 0.5;
```

If anyone has any other suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate them.  But at least this seems to be giving me the desired behavior for now.